# Instrumental unit testing of activity with FirebaseAuth

Tags: android, unit-testing, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to setup and instrumental unit test for `Activity` with `FirebaseAuth`. When I run the application, everything works just fine. The problem is within the setup of instrumental unit tests.

**Activity:**

```
public final class GoogleSignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       if (FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
       }

       mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
  }
}
```

**Test:**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class GoogleSignInActivityIntegrationTest extends UiTestPrerequesites {

@Rule
public final ActivityTestRule<GoogleSignInActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        GoogleSignInActivity.class, false, true);

@Before
public void setup(){
    if (FirebaseApp.getApps(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()).isEmpty()) {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext());
    }
}   

@Test
@SmallTest
public void implements_GoogleSignInWorkerFragment_GoogleSignInUiChangesListener() {
    //FirebaseApp.initializeApp(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()); (this doesn't help)
    assertThat(mActivityRule .getActivity(),
                notNullValue());
}
```

}

**Exception (only when running test, not app):**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.twofortyfouram.ui.test. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

Comment: Check if really you call  FirebaseApp.initializeApp(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()); in setup. I think you has never been called because of that condition

Comment: @MaherAbuthraa I've already checked it before. Even tried to add it without condition .... it gets called.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue with applicationID ( a.k.a package name ). you should add your application Id for testing to Firebase project account as well.

it has suffix: **test**

In general it looks like:

> [ApplicationID].test

i.e.

> com.apipas.android.hello.test

release applicationId is

> com.apipas.android.hello

I hope that may help you,'.